# Ajax: Data passing through button value not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Problem: All the other portions of the program works. When I add data:$("#friendadd").val() it won't update the table. I believe the problem might be with the value form? I've seen others use it to get the value of textboxes but shouldn't it still work when using a submit button?

Purpose: each user on the website has an add-as-friend button next to it. When you click on that button, I want to put the userid of that user into a database "friends".

Javascript

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#friendadd").submit(function(){//Used to be .each
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"getuser.php",
                        data:$("#friendadd").val()
                    });//Add data: and success:function
                    //$.post('getuser.php');//JSON AJAX, {UserId:"13", FriendId:"16"}
            })
        });
    </script>
```

PHP and HTML; $ctk_values are each of the users

```
    <form id="friendadd">
    <?php
        for($i=0; $i<$ctk->rowCount(); $i++){
            echo "<img src='".$ctk_values[$i][6]."' alt='Blank' style='width:64px;height:64px'>";//PP, Later add clickable profile
            echo "<th rowspan='3'>Attributes</th>";
            echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][0]."</tr>";//UN
            echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][1]."</tr>";//UL
            echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][5]."</tr>";//UA
    ?>
                <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $ctk_values[$i][4];?>"><br>
    <?php   
        }//Ends for loop
    ?>
            </form>     
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
```

getuser.php

```
<?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION)){
            session_start();
        }
        require "conn.php";
        $gtu = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO friends (AskerId, AcceptorId, mutual, type) VALUES(:AskerId, :AcceptorId, :mutual, :type)");
        $gtu->execute(array(
            'AskerId'=>$_SESSION['UserId'],
            'AcceptorId'=>$_POST['friendadd'],
            'mutual'=>false,
            'type'=>'friend'
            ));
    ?>
```

Comment: Your bound values should have the colon prefixed. `':AskerId' => $_SESSION['UserId']` for example.

Comment: `$("#friendadd")` is the id for the form or button??

Comment: Look at the browser console. You have a syntax error, you are missing a `,` after `url:"getuser.php"`. But maybe it's just a typo. Please provide a more detailed explanation of your issue. "It doesn't work" is not a suitable error description.

Comment: The `data` passed through AJAX should probably go into an associative array: `data: {friendadd : $("#friendadd").val()}`

Comment: @HalfCrazed Unfortunately that doesn't fix it, but thanks

Comment: @Norlihazmey Ghazali The form, thanks I edited it

Comment: Instead of overwriting my edit, you could have just created a new edit :P

Comment: @FelixKling sorry I have no idea haven't really an excuse though been using SO for over 2 months now. I hopefully got the edits good hang on

Comment: Still missing basic information about the problem. Have you done any debugging at all? Some basic debugging would answer these questions: Is the problem server side, or client side? Is the Ajax request sent? Does the server receive it? Is it able to process the request? Is a response sent? Does the client receive the response? Is it able to process the response? We gladly help you to solve your problem, but you first have to identify what the problem is.

Comment: @MickMnemonic wow I tried that and suddenly the query worked. But curiously $_POST['friendadd'] is always 0??? So close. No matter which user is clicked, the friends table is updated correctly but the AcceptorId is always 0. It makes no sense seeing as there's no way it could have picked up that value arbitrarily. Thanks

Comment: Well, a form doesn't have a value. Form control elements (`input`, `textarea`, etc) do. `("#friendadd").val()` should actually return `undefined`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for your patience, I don't use a PHP debugger but I've tried firebug (just got it today) and by changing around the variables I know what's not at issue. The query succeeds when there's no "data:" request. Also, I know the $_SESSION['UserId'] works after experimenting with AskerId by itself. Mutual and type don't pose a problem, the only issue from what I could tell was AcceptorId and the data request. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73500/discussion-between-script-kitty-and-felix-kling).